# How to display a view from controller action, which has been reached by an AJAX request generated from another view

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-6

In this first Laravel app I am developing, when the user loads a certain view in his browser, they are asked to enter a string (title for painting) in a prompt. When they have entered the string, an AJAX request is sent to a controller action which checks if that title already exists in DB and returns true or false. If it returns true, we need to redirect the user to another view where they can modify/update the already present record with that title. This other view also needs to be passed a bunch of data (a few arrays).

So in the `success()` method of the first ajax request which checks whether the record already exists in the database, if `true` is returned, I send another `$.ajax()` (along with one variable i am going to need in the other view) request to this controller action, which reads a bunch of data from different Models, and then packs it all up and then returns a view, passing that dataset to it.

**From the first view, after the first ajax call returns true, meaning the record is already in DB:**

```
$.ajax({
         url: url_editRecordView.url,
         data: {
                paintingTitle: dataToSend.paintingTitleByUser
         },
         method: "get",
         cache: false,
         success: function (dataReturned, stringStatus, jqXHR) {
                                console.log("dataReturned from PaintingController.displayEditRecordFormView:-");
                                console.log(dataReturned);//check
                                console.log("Type of dataReturned:-" + typeof dataReturned);
         },
         error: function (jqXHR, stringStatus, stringExceptionThrown) {
                                alert("Error! status: " + stringStatus + " ExceptionThrown: " + stringExceptionThrown);//check
         }
});
```

**And in PaintingsController in the action which is the receives the above request:**

```
public function displayEditRecordFormView (Request $request) {
        $paintingTitle = $request->input('paintingTitle');

        $allPaintingsArray = Painting::all()->toArray();
        $smPlatformsArray = SMPlatform::all()->toArray();
        $nonSmPlatformsArray = NonSMPlatform::all()->toArray();
        $galleriesArray = Gallery::all()->toArray();
        $paintersArray = Painter::all()->toArray();

        return view("paintings.editRecordForm", [
            "paintingTitle"=>$paintingTitle,
            "allPaintingsArray"=>$allPaintingsArray,
            "smPlatformsArray"=>$smPlatformsArray,
            "nonSmPlatformsArray"=>$nonSmPlatformsArray,
            "galleriesArray"=>$galleriesArray,
            "paintersArray"=>$paintersArray
        ]);
}
```

***QUESTION:***

I was expecting that when the request reaches `displayEditRecordFormView()`, the browser should open/redirect to the
view  `paintings.editRecordForm.blade.php` along with that data array passed. But practically, the above `$.ajax()` call returns with success, but in the browser, we are NOT redirected to `paintings.editRecordForm.blade.php`, and the same page remains opened. The question is why? What should I do to achieve what I need?

Comment: you don't get redirected to views, you access routes ... if you want to display that html you have to do that, there is no redirecting of anything happening ... if you just want to make a "request" then have the browser handle that response, you don't need Ajax, that is a normal request and response

Comment: @lagbox I had to redirect to a view, say view B, from another view, say view A (essentially from javascript in viewA because as a result of an ajax response, we get to decide if we want to go to viewB), along with passing a few arrays of data. So in order to send that much data, I decided to relay through a controller action (where I have all that data available, except one variable which has dynamically just been generated in view A) rather than redirecting - continued in next comment

Comment: @lagbox continued from previous comment - via `location.reload()` (remember we are in Javascript here). So i sent AJAX request to the controller action with that one variable, and there I pack that one variable along with a few arrays of data available in the controller, and do `return view(viewBAddress, [dataToSendToViewB]);`. AJAX is supposed to be Asynchrnous. **But my browser never goes to viewB. That's the problem I have here.**